# Gradient texture not showing up in render in Eevee

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

So I am making this simple low poly landscape.
[image: Layout image of low poly landscape]

The large plane to the left is meant to be colored used a gradient texture, using this node setup:

[image: Node system for gradient texture]

However, this texture does not show up in the final render giving me just a uniform shade of purple like this:

[image: incorrect render]

The texture also does not show in the 3D Viewport on render mode. However it *does* show up in the viewport if I select the plane and switch to local editing with numpad '/'. It also shows up if I do a 'Viewport Render Image' from the 'view' menu.

[image: Viewport render image]

So I'm guessing this is an issue with rendering settings - I have not changed any from the default for this other than changing the image dimensions to produce a square image. I am using Eevee and Blender 2.82.7. The texture does render correctly with Cycles but I would like to know why this isn't working in Eevee. Thank you in advance

James

Comment: I can't confirm that under 2.9x ... any reason to stay with 2.82 (it seems to be a bug, even I didnt experienced such thing in that time and primarily - it isn't going to be fixed ... it is rather better to use 2.83 LTS (if you cant use last official release for some reason) that is maintained. Or share file to confirm it is not something with your file (or try replicate with a new file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this really explains the difference between Viewport and Render, but here are a couple of things to try?

Hard to tell from your render, but you may be getting your gradient OK, just along the wrong axis? Given a full 3D vector, Linear Gradient seems to select X, for mapping. If your mountains are up in Z, you might want to isolate that value:

[image]

..if you wanted your gradient bottom to top.

You're using *Generated* coordinates, which measure 0->1 along the each side of your object's bounding box. The origin is at min(X,Y,Z) of that box. (If you rotate the texture without moving it first, that will be the center of rotation.) So there's another possibility...

Check that box by checking 'Bounds' in the object's *Object Properties* tab > *Viewport Display* panel. If you have some extraneous geometry, and the box is much bigger than the bit of the object you're interested in, you may be at  one end of your gradient?

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions Robin. I couldn't get it to work with the separated XYZ but switching from Generated to Object co-ordinates did.